# Where do I get the complete fictional data (the titles of Movies/ TV, Characters, People/ cast/ crew) dump

Tags: data-request, film

Freebase is shutting down. 
but I am unable to download the 25GB of zipped file (shows error) dump they are providing.
I used their API to set up my search bar, (segregated into 3 sections Movie titles, Character Titles, People Titles ) but the challenge is there appears to be unnecessary fine filtering like film series, docudrama, historical film, fantasy film,... and a never ending list just for the movies.

Is there a way I could unite all the multiple titles into one. Apart from free base is there any dump provider who does the way I want.